Lenovo P3 - Can I run RTX A2000 plus GTX 1080 together?
I just bought a Lenovo P3 with an RTX A2000 12GB card in it. It has a 2nd PCIe slot and 8pin power (6+2); I have a GTX 1080 from an old system I tried to add to the current setup (A2000 in first PCIe slot, GTX 1080 in 2nd slot) but I get a bluescreen on startup. Tried updating to latest RTX drivers, looked promising but Windows then indicated it was "uninstalling this device" on the A2000 in device manager, and then proceeding to bluescreen.
Am I doing something wrong? Thanks for any help!

what's your end goal here?

Got it working! And inference with Ollama shows distribution to both GPUs. Recipe:
With only the RTX in place, video cables to the IGP + RTX, BIOS Video set to Auto
DDU x 2.
https://www.guru3d.com/download/display-driver-uninstaller-download/
Run DDU and do clean + reboot (top option).
At this point Device Manager should show the integrated graphics + a generic video adapter.
Shut down
Install the GTX 1080
Start the system and then install the Vulkan 1.3 Beta Drivers
At this point Device Manager should show the integrated graphics + two generic video adapters.
https://developer.nvidia.com/downloads/vulkan-beta-55331-windows
Reboot
Once restarted, Device Manager should show the integrated graphics + a generic video adapter + GTX 1080
Install NVidia drivers with NVCleanstall
Should detect the RTX A2000 12GB as the primary video card
Choose Add Hardware Support
Template for the GTX 1080
DevID should be identical to the DevID in [] (for the 1080, it was 1B80)
Reboot
Task Manager and Device Manager will show GPU 0 (Integrated Graphics) GPU 1 (RTX), GPU 2 (GTX)
nvidia-smi shows both devices as well; during the ollama run for gemma2 27B, shows VRAM and utilization on both cards.
